# Using VMWare Shared folders with Open VM Tools

Tags: 14.04

I'd like to use Open VM tools instead of VmWare tools that come with VMWare workstation to mount shared folders, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Nobody answered but I found the solution elsewhere this works fine.

1. Setup the shared folder in VM settings
2. Reboot might be required
3. Create a directory you'll use as a mount point in /mnt, I called mine YourMountDriveName
4. Use this command
5. sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/YourMountDriveName -o         allow_other

This should mount a shared directory to the directory that was created in step 3.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly with `open-vm-tools` on ArchLinux